# Mongoose InsertMany not returning the _id of the saved documents in results

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Im trying to save a list of vehicles into my mlab (mongodb) using mongoose. And this is my query:

```
Vehicle.insertMany(req.body, function(err, result){
        //**req.body is a list of Vehicle objects**
        if (err){
            res.status(400).send( { message: 'Could not save the vehicles', meta: err } );
        } 
        else{
            res.status(200).send( { message: 'Successfully saved the vehicles', data: result } );
        }
    });
```

And this is my Vehicle Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const vehicleSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    name: String,
    type: String
});

const Vehicle = mongoose.model('vehicle', vehicleSchema);

module.exports = Vehicle;
```

The result of Vehicle.InsertMany returns the below:

```
{
    "message": "Successfully saved the vehicles",
    "data": [
          {
             "name": "KIA",
             "type": "four wheeler",
             "__v": 0
          },
          {
             "name": "BDY",
             "type": "four wheeler",
             "__v": 0
          }
     ],
}
```

My problem is, **why isn't the result returning the _id field of the saved documents**? And what is __v field?

(PS: Mongoose docs doesnt mention anything about _id in the insertMany documentation. Also, Im new to Mongoose and not sure if my Schema is correct)

Please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id: "*Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an _id field by default if one is not passed into the Schema constructor.*" Since you specify `_id: String,` it's your responsibility to set the value.

Comment: @AlexBlex It worked. Thanks. :)

Do you know what __v field stands for?

Comment: @AlexBlex It does indeed, and I didnt know. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks so much. I thought it was a bug in mongoose. :)